# How to trim the enclosures (''some text") reading CSV file in PHP

Tags: php, json

I am trying to use a web API to get some data. The problem is that I need to convert CSV data to JSON format.

```
<?php
    // allows us to skip the first row while looping through the file 
     $i = 0;
    //web api
    $stocks = "https://www.google.com/finance/historical?output=csv&q=aapl";

    //read csv file
    $handle = fopen($stocks, 'r');
    //loop through CSV file
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 2000, ",")) !== FALSE) {    
        if ($i > 0) { 
            trim($data[0]);
            trim($data[1]);
            trim($data[2]);
            trim($data[3]);
            trim($data[4]);
            trim($data[5]);

            // an array
            $chartArray[] = $data;
        }
        $i++;
    }

   fclose($handle);

   //Convert PHP Array to JSON String
   print (json_encode($chartArray));

?>
```

[image: Screenshot]

As you can see from the image, I am getting JSON with enclosure. `["19-May-17","153.38","153.98","152.63","153.06","26960788"]`.

Please let me know if there is a solution. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why give an image that just has text? Where is this *"some text"* that needs to be trimed, what's the issue with the result?

Comment: ["19-May-17","153.38","153.98","152.63","153.06","26960788"] this is what I am getting. vs What I need  [19-May-17,153.38,153.98,152.63,153.06,26960788]

Comment: `19-May-17` isn't a valid value, but why not just convert those items to a number and `"19-May-17"` to a date?

Comment: good point !!! Just do not know how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will never ever put non-string values into a json. Never.

Otherwise. You can simply convert the number parts to number, and the date parts to php date.

Something like this:

```
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 2000, ",")) !== FALSE) {    
    if ($i > 0) { 

        $data[0] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($data[0]));
        $data[1] = intval($data[1]);
        $data[2] = intval($data[2]);
        $data[3] = intval($data[3]);
        $data[4] = intval($data[4]);
        $data[5] = intval($data[5]);

        $chartArray[] = $data;
    }
    $i++;
}
```

But as soon as you convert it to a json, it will auto-place the " chars. So you will need to convert the strings at reciever (client?) side.

Comment: This is so much better!!! The only thing that I have problem is the date. This is what I am getting . ["2017-05-19",153,153,152,153,26960788]

Comment: Oh, of course. I just messed up the date formatting. Change `date('Y-m-d'` to `date('d-M-y'`

Comment: I am trying to output the data on client side to draw a candlestick chart.

Comment: Which language do you use for client side? (VanillaJS or some fw?)

Comment: Yes VanillaJS . I am trying to finish a school project (StockSimulator) in PHP(slim/twig) and we need to draw some candlestick charts. It is a little bit challenging since this is my first project.

Comment: Maybe ask a new question with the consuming JS function, since posting new codes and answers in comment section is a bit awful.

Comment: Agree! Thank you again for your support! Really helpful !

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstand what JSON is. This is what your data looks like when it is in JSON format: It must be a series of values that are legal in the `JSON` subset of javascript syntax (string, `int`, array, etc.). There is no problem to solve. The function that consumes JSON will know what to do.

Comment: The date format looks fine the only problem that remains is the enclosures around the date ["19-05-2017",153,153,152,153,26960788] and I need to keep the numbers as decimal 153.38 vs int 153.

Comment: For decimal I used floatval  vs intval and it works.

Comment: Indeed, javascript and JSON have floats too. The point is you don't need to worry about the quotes around strings, they belong there.

Comment: You are absolutely right! Now I understand your point. I am getting the chart with all data points.